# create a ftp user, but not able to access child directories

Tags: windows-server-2008, ftp

I create a ftp site at:

f:\domains

I created a ftp user, and gave full permissions to the domains folder.

When connecting via FTP, I can't see any sub folders inside the domains directory.
I am able to create a folder, and I can see that folder.

How can I have the permissions propagate to the child folders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on subfolder under Domains: Properties --> Security --> Advanced --> make sure Inherit from Parent is checked.